# XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location in Console FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm use ASP.NET MVC end I take this error only in FF. Why I take this error message?  What is the cause of this?
I don't understand where the source of this error. Anyone have any thoughts?

[image]

Next Error:
[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Check this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2e64c4dc-72d0-4d20-9f35-d72c02bc0a72/xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-location-httpsomething2011defaultaspx-line-number-1?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) for more information

> Based on my research, the error message is only generated by FireFox
>   when the render page is blank in Internet. For some reason, .NET
>   generates a response type of "application/xml" when it creates an
>   empty page. Firefox parses the file as XML and finding no root
>   element, spits out the error message.

in other words, this is a **known Firefox issue**

Comment: In internet explorer, I don't get the error but it only does not work like expected.

Comment: `For some reason, .NET generates a response type of "application/xml" when it creates an empty page` This is not true, there is no Content-Type in empty response

Comment: This bug still exists in Firefox. :E

Comment: Getting this when using Discord via Browser >< Solution is to set `privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator` to false.

Answer (score 6):

```
public IActionResult MethodName()
{
    // YOUR CODE 
    return StatusCode(204);
}
```

Code 204 -The server successfully processed the request, and is not returning any content

For more details about status code check this page:
[List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success)

Answer (score 5):

I changed the type of return value in Action method and it worked. More details can be found in [my article on this topic](https://ovinitech.blogspot.com/2019/01/xml-parsing-error-no-root-element-found.html).

Changed from

```
return Ok();
```

to

```
return Json("Ok");
```

Comment: You could also return NoContent();  Which is more or less equivalent to return StatusCode(204);  return Ok(null); will also make Firefox happy.  The difference between the two is explained very well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861379/oknull-vs-nocontent-in-asp-net-core-which-is-more-efficient

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem with

```
return NoContent();
```

It seems more clear When you want to return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in my app by setting the `Content-Type` header on the server to `text/plain`. Like this in Node:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Use whatever MIME type is appropriate for your data, ie `application/json`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the `XML Parsing error: no root element` error in a few different situations. It's typically present in the Firefox developer console only.

1. Returning a `200 OK` response code with an empty body. Your server should instead return a `204 No Content` response code.
2. Returning a `204 No Content` response code and then attaching content to the response. Your server should instead return a `200 OK` response code.
3. Returning an incorrect `Content-Type`. Set it to the same type that's used in your response body (JSON, XML, plaintext, etc.), or it could get parsed incorrectly.

If none of these fixes your issue, I would review all of your response headers for correctness. Other fields like `Content-Length` could presumable interfere as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the top Google result for this error message and I don't see an answer covering another tricky case yet, so here goes:

This will also happen if your SVG is served correctly, but is missing the closing `</svg>` tag! For example, in case the response is only served partially, because it is a streaming response and it errors out mid-way…

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error when POSTing an axios call. And our test server was not in the

```
allowed-origin:
```

list of hosts. Adding our server to allowed-origin in the application.yml resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen too, if you have a [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on your controller action and try to submit the form without an actual token. You can render the token explicitly with

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

which is the preferred solution or remove the validation attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by returning OkObjectResult instead of Ok().

Old Code:

```
Return Ok();
```

New Code:

```
return new OkObjectResult(true);
```

Note: OkObjectResult can be used after adding namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `about:config` and set:

```
privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator = false
```

The warning won't appear.