# .Net Core 2.2. Calling Identity Razor page ajax methods

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm doing a .Net Core 2.2 project and trying to customize (or rather add) a few Identity pages. My project is not razor pages. However, when I scaffolded out the Identity pages that I needed, they appear to be Razor pages.

Identity creates an Areas directory structure like so:

> Areas/Pages/Account/Manage

I've added a Razor page which creates the following files inside the Manage folder:

> ManageProfilePicture.cshtml
>
> ManageProfilePicture.cshtml.cs

I'm using the default `OnGet` and `OnPut` methods to do other stuff (choose, upload and manipulate the image) and therefore want to call a separate ajax method to save the image. I've tried using a `handler` and verification token as other SO questions and articles suggest, but can't seem to get anything other than a 404 on calling the link in my ajax:

My method in the code behind is like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveProfilePictureAsync(string t, string l, string h, string w, string fileName)
    {
                var userName = User.Identity.Name;
                  ...
    }
```

My javascript looks like so:

```
$('#saveProfilePicture').on('click', function () {
        var img = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img');
        $('#avatar-crop-box button').addClass('disabled');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Identity/Account/Manage/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: {
    ...
    }
```

I know I'm getting to where it tries the url in that code as I've `console.log`(ged) other variables in there from the `data` section of my ajax call (length, width, etc values). Plus, I can see the url change each time in the 404 message.

My ajax cshtml button is:

```
<button id="saveProfilePicture" class="btn btn-default">SaveProfilePictureAsync</button> (inside and outside different form tags)
```

For the ajax `url`, I've tried:

```
/Identity/Account/Manage/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture
/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture
```

I've tried what seems like a million other variations of that url (examples):

Swapping `pagehandler=` in place of `handler=` as well as `/SaveProfilePicture` to replace the entire `handler` querystring parameter.

Swapping `SaveProfilePicture` with all variations of what my `ActionResult` is actually called (`OnPastSaveProfilePictureAsync`, `SaveProfilePictureAsync`, etc)

The following code (non-js post) gets me to my method:

```
<form asp-page-handler="saveProfilePicture" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

and shows (in Firefox inspect element) `/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture` as the file section and `/Identity/Account/Manage/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture` in the referrer properties.

The exact error is always (with variations in the url when I change it):

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found
>   Location: https://localhost:44366/Identity/Account/Manage/ManageProfilePicture?handler=saveProfilePicture
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

At this point I  feel like I'm simply missing something entirely fundamental and am out of ideas. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Per the comments, different browsers show slightly different errors:

Chrome:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Opera:

> POST
>   https://localhost:44366/Identity/Account/Manage/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture 400

Edge:

> HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the
>   server due to invalid syntax. (XHR)POST -
>   https://localhost:44366/Identity/Account/Manage/ManageProfilePicture?handler=SaveProfilePicture

Starting to look like it was never a 404 and maybe not processing the verification token properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487220/xml-parsing-error-no-root-element-found-location-in-console-ff check this out.. did you try in other browsers?

Comment: @MohanRamalingam Interesting... I did. I tried Chrome and Edge as well. I assumed the errors were the same, but they are not... slightly different and at least gives me something to go on... I'll post the different errors...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
```

To:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
```

All is well now after insanity has started to set in. See you guys soon...